# How loop variable really works

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, scope

Can someone explain me why **var** doesn't overwrite previous values inside **for** loop. I know that **var** overwrite values when is in function and then I should use **let** or **anonymous function**. Below is an simple example:

```
for (var a=0; a<10; a++) {
  console.log(a);
}
```

Output is from 0-9. But since **var** has function scope, in my reasoning the variable should be overwritten and output 9 times the same number(9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I understand your question.

So, your first example. Output cannot be overwritten. It's output. Part of the name is you put it out. So it's 0, put the 0 out. Now it's 1, put the 1 out. Now it's 2, put the 2 out. And so on.

In your second example, there's a time out. So those functions don't execute until the for loop is finished. Once the for loop is finished, a = 10. Output 10. a is still 10. Output 10 again.